# How to work "if np.array([False]):"

Tags: python, numpy

The output of the following code is **NOTHING**.

```
if np.array([False]):
  print("hello")
```

Although I tried to search for it, I don't know how it works. Can Python overload `if`?

The following is a case of a pure array.

```
if [False]:
  print("hello")
```

The output is `hello`

Would you tell me how to code np.array?

Comment: Yes, you can override it using [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in Python 3 and  [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You answer make me understand.

Comment: Why are you trying this?  Using a numpy array in an if expression almost never works as people expect.

Answer (score 2):

It seems np.array([]) returns False and so do for `0` and `False`

```
>>> bool(np.array([]))
False
>>> bool(np.array([0]))
False
>>> bool(np.array([False]))
False
```

Here the list returns true if it has any item..

```
>>> bool([False])   ### the returned boolean value is based on the length of the list.
True
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing i noticed is `if np.array([False])` or `bool(np.array([False])` returns the bool of the only item in the array. And you are not supposed to have more than one item in numpy array if you are doing `if` or `bool`.

If there are more than one elements, have to use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

```
>>> if np.array([False, False]):
...   print 's'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> bool(np.array([False, False]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
>>>
>>> bool(np.array([False, 232]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
>>>
>>> bool(np.array([False, 232]).any())
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`if [False]:` will always be `True` because `[Flase]` is a list with one item (i.e., non-empty), so the `if` block will be entered and you will see the output of your `print` call.

`np.array([False])`

returns a `numpy.ndarray`, which in this case evaluates to `False`, so the `if` block will never be entered and you will not see any output.